# Cannot open a package from the Unity Asset Store website

Tags: unity, windows, asset-management

Yesterday I found an asset on the Unity Asset Store website, clicked the button "Open in Unity", and it was opened in Unity.

Today, when I did the same thing, I got the error message below:

[image]

I opened the Defaults Apps page in Windows 10 Settings. But what do I do from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not find a solution, but I found a workaround:

- In the Unity website, click "Add to My Assets";
- Go to the Unity editor;
- Open the Asset Store window;
- Click my initials (at the top-right corner; for me they are ES);
- Click "My Assets";
- Find the desired asset, click Download and then click Import.

I still do not understand why clicking "Open in Unity" in the website stopped working, and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I think that for some reason windows doesn't know what application to open the package with. You should open unity and go to `Assets -> Import package -> Custom package` and just open the file.

Answer (score 0):

[Generally for questions about Windows configuration, you can ask on Super User](https://superuser.com/search?q=%5Bwindows%5D+default+program).

You can scroll to the bottom of the Default apps window and choose "Choose default apps by file type" then scroll down to UnityPackage and click "Choose a default" - then pick your Unity version of choice.

[image: Choose default apps window]

If you can't get Windows to recognize the Unity package type, then you can also open your Unity project and pull the package in with `Assets > Import Package`

[image: Import package menu]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, but it was due to a missing editor version.

In my case, I run 2020 LTS; I tested 2022, then removed 2022, but Windows regedit still retains the latest installed version:

To fix this, search for a key containing `unity.exe` in regedit, then modify the regkey with you current version, to something like this.

Key:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Unity package file\shell\edit\command
```

Value:

```
"C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.3.26f1\Editor\Unity.exe" -openfile "%1"
```